# Create custom token address

Tags: spl-token, spl

spl-token create-token token-key-pair-file

Can this command create same token address with wallet address?

When I see “spl-token create-token —help” it provides keypair argument.

Answer (score 1):

`spl-token create-token [TOKEN_KEYPAIR]` creates a token with the mint as the same address as the public key of the keypair file created.

So let's say you have the keypair file `/path/to/keypair.json` with a public key of `Fjyud2VXixk2vCs4DkBpfpsq48d81rbEzh6deKt7WvPj`. If you used `spl-token create-token /path/to/keypair.json`, your token mint would have the address `Fjyud2VXixk2vCs4DkBpfpsq48d81rbEzh6deKt7WvPj`.